# Check if condition is met in the days before current (R)

Tags: r, date, conditional-statements

I have a database form by dates, with measures every hour. If this measure is grater than 5 then meets criteria 1 (I did this already using mutate in dplyr)
Like this:

| date | hour | Measure | Meets_criteria_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | 00:00:00 | 7 | 1 |
| 01/01/2020 | 01:00:00 | 12 | 1 |
| 01/01/2020 | 02:00:00 | 3 | 0 |
| ............ |  |  |  |
| 10/01/2020 | 21:00:00 | 2 | 0 |
| 10/01/2020 | 22:00:00 | 15 | 1 |
| 10/01/2020 | 23:00:00 | 20 | 1 |

Now, I want to know how many times in one day a the condition is met. To do this, I summed all the "1s" in "Meets_criteria_1" grouping by day:

| date | hour | Meets_criteria_1 | Sum_criteria_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | 00:00:00 | 1 | 3 |
| 01/01/2020 | 01:00:00 | 1 | 3 |
| 01/01/2020 | 02:00:00 | 0 | 3 |
| ............ |  |  |  |
| 10/01/2020 | 21:00:00 | 0 | 11 |
| 10/01/2020 | 22:00:00 | 1 | 11 |
| 10/01/2020 | 23:00:00 | 1 | 11 |

However, I need a third condition to meet criteria 2, which is "In the two previous days the "Sum_criteria_1" is at least 6"

My question is:
How do I tell R to check the two previous days to the current?
So, for example if I am looking at the date 08/01/2020 the condition is met only if the sum_criteria_1 was at least 6 on the 06/01/2020 and on the 07/01/2020.

Edit:
I tried using lag as this but I just get NAs:

```
mutate(yesterday = lag(sum_criteria_1, n=1), 
       day_before = lag(sum_criteria_1, n = 2))
```

Any help will be more than welcome!
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(dat[1:48,])` (I used 48 to ensure two days.

Comment: Use `dplyr::lag() `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like this

```
df %>% mutate(meets_criteria_1 = ifelse(Measure > 5, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(sum_criteria = sum(meets_criteria_1)) %>%
  mutate(criteria2 = ifelse(lag(sum_criteria) >= 6 & lag(sum_criteria,2), 1, 0)) %>%
  right_join(df, by = "Date")
```

## Sample data

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", 
"01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", 
"01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", 
"01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", 
"01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", "01-01-2020", 
"01-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", 
"02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", 
"02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", 
"02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", 
"02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", "02-01-2020", 
"03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", 
"03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", 
"03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", 
"03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", 
"03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "03-01-2020", "04-01-2020", 
"04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", 
"04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", 
"04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", 
"04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", 
"04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "04-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", 
"05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", 
"05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", 
"05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", 
"05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", "05-01-2020", 
"05-01-2020", "05-01-2020"), Hour = c("00:00:00", "01:00:00", 
"02:00:00", "03:00:00", "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "06:00:00", "07:00:00", 
"08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", 
"14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", 
"20:00:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", "23:00:00", "00:00:00", "01:00:00", 
"02:00:00", "03:00:00", "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "06:00:00", "07:00:00", 
"08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", 
"14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", 
"20:00:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", "23:00:00", "00:00:00", "01:00:00", 
"02:00:00", "03:00:00", "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "06:00:00", "07:00:00", 
"08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", 
"14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", 
"20:00:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", "23:00:00", "00:00:00", "01:00:00", 
"02:00:00", "03:00:00", "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "06:00:00", "07:00:00", 
"08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", 
"14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", 
"20:00:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", "23:00:00", "00:00:00", "01:00:00", 
"02:00:00", "03:00:00", "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "06:00:00", "07:00:00", 
"08:00:00", "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "13:00:00", 
"14:00:00", "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "19:00:00", 
"20:00:00", "21:00:00", "22:00:00", "23:00:00"), Measure = c(2L, 
14L, 4L, 19L, 0L, 15L, 13L, 17L, 3L, 19L, 0L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 
8L, 7L, 13L, 14L, 4L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 12L, 18L, 7L, 
13L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 18L, 19L, 14L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 17L, 
14L, 20L, 1L, 15L, 18L, 1L, 12L, 5L, 0L, 20L, 19L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 
8L, 8L, 0L, 15L, 16L, 20L, 14L, 18L, 17L, 3L, 15L, 14L, 4L, 17L, 
16L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 0L, 15L, 3L, 12L, 17L, 6L, 4L, 16L, 4L, 
15L, 0L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 15L, 10L, 12L, 19L, 13L, 3L, 18L, 14L, 
11L, 18L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 1L, 18L, 16L, 14L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 16L, 
10L, 2L, 12L, 10L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-120L))
```

## check result

```
# A tibble: 120 x 5
   Date       sum_criteria criteria2 Hour     Measure
   <chr>             <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>      <int>
 1 01-01-2020           17        NA 00:00:00       2
 2 01-01-2020           17        NA 01:00:00      14
 3 01-01-2020           17        NA 02:00:00       4
 4 01-01-2020           17        NA 03:00:00      19
 5 01-01-2020           17        NA 04:00:00       0
 6 01-01-2020           17        NA 05:00:00      15
 7 01-01-2020           17        NA 06:00:00      13
 8 01-01-2020           17        NA 07:00:00      17
 9 01-01-2020           17        NA 08:00:00       3
10 01-01-2020           17        NA 09:00:00      19
# ... with 110 more rows
```

Comment: Didn't it serve the purpose?

Comment: hi @AnilGoyal - I am getting some issues. My original data-set is huge, which 70 sites, 365 days and 24 measures per day. I cannot summarise and rejoin.... but I am trying to find a way! i'll keep you updated. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: That's why sample data is always advised.  Nevertheless use `site` in group_by and by arg in right_join; u will be able to get the results

Comment: would you mind explaining to me what does this do exactly? why is the condition of being >=6 only in the first term?
ifelse(lag(sum_criteria) >= 6 & lag(sum_criteria,2)

Comment: The first two dates will obviously be NA.  Next rows in each group(summarise will render one row in each group) will be 1 or 0 depending upon your condition that previous two rows are both greater than 5 or not.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now! :)

Comment: Glad to have been help.  Please also upvote as desired on SO.